# AVAudioPlayer EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: avaudioplayer

I am trying to pause the `AVAudioPlayer` if it is currently playing.  When I debug my code and check `AVAudioPlayer`, I see it is allocated.  When I try to access a method/property on it (i.e. `myAudioPlayer isPlaying`), I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.  This happens if the `AVAudioPlayer` does not have a sound loaded.  Is there a way I can do a check to see if it has loaded a sound?  I tried accessing `myAudioPlayer.data`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you post some code?  My guess is that you are accessing the AVAudioPlayer before it is initialized.

Comment: try to check if it initialized properly https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2whoaz/avaudioplayer_issue_with_stopping_and_checking_if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to use [prepareToPlay](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) method to find whether it has loaded or not.

Answer (score 7):

For me it was because I wasn't calling the one of the designated initialisers. I was instantiating it with `AVAudioPlayer()` instead of the designated initialisers which are `public init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL) throws` and `public init(data: NSData) throws`

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 13, make sure you are removing the initialization on AVAudioPlayer before asigning it with AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(...))

i.e. change 
`var audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()` to `var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!`

Comment: Great shot, this is the real problem, the empty initialization before using..

Comment: This is it for iOS13! How did you discover the solution Reid?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add AVFoundation Framework.Then,import AVFounadtion framework in .h file.

.h:

```
 AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

.m:

```
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audio1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url1 error:&error];
    //audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

        [audioPlayer play];
```

Try this code it may help you..