# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x38)

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, exc-bad-access

In a view controller I have an action method for a button. In the body of the method it says

```
if audioPlayer.playing {

    audioPlayer.stop

}
```

When the audio player is playing, everything works. When the audio player is NOT playing i get the crash error. I'm literally losing my sanity help me please for the love of god.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670430/avaudioplayer-exc-bad-access

Comment: Use this `audioPlayer.stop()`

Comment: i fixed it. I needed to initalize audioPlayer with arguments. Before I just audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(). Now I have audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(args).